Cells after index 25, section 1 not showing in CollectionView on iPhone Xs
Collection View with top few image showing and bottom 3 not showing (click to see the picture)
We have a CollectionView with 2 sections, first being UILabel and second UIImageView
Cells are created here
    func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                         cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath)

In debugger we can see that system does not call this function if indexPath.section == 1 and indexPath.row > 25.
This only happens on iPhone XS and its simulator and not on any other device.
Any ideas how to fix that?
thanks a lot!
We've tried non-reusable cells, tried reloading only visible rows, DispatchQueue
